# How to use string with integer variable value combine in range function?

Tags: jinja2

How can I use jinja2 to concatenate strings and numbers.

Ansible 2.5 .

I have two variables Point1 and Point2 and both are integer variables(some randome numbers based on some calculation.
Point1 = 5
Point2 = 7

Here, I want to use them in range function. How would I use them.

```
{% for x in range(2) %}
---
{% for i in range('Point'+x|string) %} <!-- here I'm trying to access Point1 and Point2 variable values one by one-->
---
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried like below as well but the value is becoming as zero.

```
{% set point = ('point'+x|string)|int %}
```

Range function requires integer value but here I'm giving string value.

Please suggest me how can I access those values in range function.

Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it's better not try to access external variables by name but use the another approach. Look:

```
{% set points=[Point1, Point2] %}

{% for x in range(2) %}
# ---
{% for i in range(points[x]) %}
> ---
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

At the first line you make an array of `Point1` and `Point2` values. Next, in loops, everything you need is to access this array by index. You'll got the same result as you want but with smaller effort.